# One torrent file downloading speed is depending on the other torrent file which is being downloaded

Tags: bittorrent, speed

Today I encountered a strange problem when downloading a new torrent file.
I had paused another torrent file with a healthy seeding list 2 days earlier (2 separate files). Today, when I am downloading this new torrent file with 2 seeders, the download was very low like 10-20KB/s.
But when I am trying to continue to download that other older file, this new file downloading speed will increase along with the older file. This was not a coincidence.
I tried like 10 times, this thing is happening again and again. I am using Bittorrent client 7.10.

Comment: In some rare edge cases, uTP can cause this behaviour. Try [disabling uTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44434604/how-does-utorrent-choose-between-tcp-and-utp/44435399#44435399) and see if it gets better. If there's no difference activate uTP again, because it's generally better for bittorrenting than TCP.